# Uploading File in jsp or multipart/form-data

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

Actually I am trying to get no of files count to be uploading before uploading using common upload lib in jsp and I made a function for getting the counts of file this is here:

```
public static int getUploadFileCount(HttpServletRequest request) throws FileUploadException
{
    int Result = 0;

    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : items) 
    {
        if (!item.isFormField())
        Result++;
    }       

    return Result;
}
```

And use this function in business logic this here:

```
public void doChangeProfilePhoto(HttpServletRequest request) throws FileUploadException
{
    if(UploadFileUtil.getUploadFileCount(request) != 1)
        throw new FileUploadException("There is Multiple/None File upload for Profile Photo. ");
    ProfileImage newProfileImage = new ProfileImage();
    newProfileImage.setFileName("sam.jpg");
    if(new UploadBPOProfilePhotoImpl().uploadPhoto(newProfileImage, request))
    {}
}
```

And in this code after calling uploadPhoto function there is also use same code for retrieving the files one by one like this:

```
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : items) // Did not get file if i already used this code once For getting the files count:
    {
        if (!item.isFormField())
        //did for makeing file and writing/saving it with a name
    }
```

So here I get problem is that when I use this code its not get file when I have used the same code for counting the files

and if I comment this two line where I have use to get files count in doChangeProfilePhoto like this:

```
//if(UploadFileUtil.getUploadFileCount(request) != 1)
//    throw new FileUploadException("There is Multiple/None File upload for Profile Photo. ");
```

Then its working. Why its happening that if one time it is used so after it unable to retrieving the file.What's the reason behind it
and is there any way to count files using common upload...and also for their names?

Comment: This seems to be that UploadFileUtil read the "inputstream" to count them.

Comment: in that function only for (FileItem item : items)  is retriving and checking for the file field in form submit

Comment: ok, I was confused... getUploadFileCount are consuming the inputstream... you need to "rewind" (may be not posible), or treat input in "one-shot mode".

Comment: see that this code used in second to get files

Comment: List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();
             
            // iterates over form's fields
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                // processes only fields that are not form fields
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = newProfileImage.getFileName();